# My program does not output the right decimal numbers of an arithmetic average. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I need to display the correct arithmetic average of a series of integers entered by the user.
If the user enters 6, 9, 7, and 4, the average should be 6.5 but instead displays 6.0. Why does that happen? I used an ArrayList to store all the integers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;

public class QuizScoreStatistics
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> Scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        int a = 0;

        while(a != 99) {
            System.out.println("Enter scores");
            a = input.nextInt();
            if(a != 99) {
                if ( a > 10 || a < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Score must be between 10 and 0");
            }
            else {
                Scores.add(a);
            }

            i++;
        } 
    }
        int max = Collections.max(Scores);

        int min = Collections.min(Scores);

        int sum = 0;

        double averg = 0;

        for( i = 0; i <= Scores.size() - 1; i++) {
             sum += Scores.get(i);
        }
        averg = sum / Scores.size();

        System.out.println("Scores entered " + i);

        System.out.println("Highest score " + max);

        System.out.println("Lowest score "+ min);

        System.out.println("Average: "+ averg);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should change your data from integer to `double`.  Integer math removes the decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

I won't try to give away the entire question I think you could probably answer that yourself given a nudge in the right direction.

You correctly identified that your `averg` is a double because your answer could come out to something like 6.7 or 2.3 or whatever. Thats a correct assumption to make! However during your "arithmetic process" you are using integers to do the division, which will come out as an integer. I will repeat the actual DIVISION is happening with two integers , can you see where the bug is coming from?

If you need more of a push to see the exact remedy of this solution I would point you here 
https://programming.guide/java/wrong-results-for-division.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had forgotten about that interaction!

Answer (score 1):

Try  `averg = (1.0 *sum) / Scores.size();`
 because `int/int => int` but `double/int=>double`

Comment: Thanks a lot Traian

Comment: You shouldn't do a multiplication by a hardcoded value such as 1.0 to cast to double, better cast the value: averg = (double) sum / Scores.size()

Comment: @JihedAmine why not ? same thing

Comment: @Jonathan Mejia, another option to avoid casting is to change declaration of `sum` to `double` and keep `averg` as it was. So even `sum` is populated always with `int`, due to definition the result will be always `double` (so do not care how sum is obtain); see first comment @ markspace

Comment: "Why not? same thing" because its not obvious why you're doing that multiplication, explicit casting more clearly explains what it does. Its better to use the things in the way they are for.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo, `it's obvious as you liked to be` ... a working solution is always fine and if you could choose then it's up to you

Comment: Hm, it's actually a matter for other discussion, but it's often a bad practice to write the code for yourself only, every developer working with a language should know what the casting means and why it's used, but you need to explain somehow why you choose multiplication when the language provides the mechanism to do what you want to do.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo it's always up to the developer to use any solution might like (if there are not any constrains). Also my answer provide all the information needed in the short way. Here is a trivial problem so nothing more to detail. Hardly to understand why you have to choose always what language provided if there are option, and maybe your is better ?

Comment: How better? Multiple options is good and it's good when you think carefully which one to choose. You dont use what you like most, you try to choose the best option in your specific situation. You dont use sum `n` times if you want multiplication, even though you like it better. I don't say anything bad about your answer, you provided an alternative solution and it's good. I just wrote why it might not be a good idea to use it in production code. By the way, if you think your alternative is better than others, its good to provide how it's better in your answer.

Comment: Multiple solutions is not about having fun by choosing what you like the most, multiple options is a good point to start thinking about the problem and solutions and decide which is best for your situation.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo Here the answer provided is FINE and good to choose if wanted in any scenarios. Nothing more. It's not about doing the same thing as doing sun on n times when you can choose multiplication, you just extended in the wrong way.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo `Multiple solutions is not about having fun by choosing what you like the most` ... could have fun also ... said other `multiple proper solution` and after choose whateveer is best for you. There are not any "forced" choices as you try to argues. Even "have fun" is a criteria in choosing

Comment: Look carefully at your comments and see that I just answered to your question, why this multiplication might be bad. Then you said when you have multiple options it's fine to choose what you want. This is why I provided the example, it's not an extension, it's just another option to solve the problem and why it might be bad to choose what you want not seeing at a specific context. What about your answer I also said that I'm totally fine with it and it's super cool that you provided another options. I just answered another question. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough explaining my thoughts.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo shortly you said my answer is BAD because it's not used language capabilities and never to use it. Implicit casting (1.0) is wrong because it's not using explicit (cast). This is what you wanted to proved. Said one more time. Answer provide is FINE and could choose it in any scenarios, even in production if wanted. What I wanted to point is that many time a programmer always have from where to choose in the proper way. Then it' s just up to programmer to made the decision. There are not any forced choices !!!  or implicit one which is mandatory to choose ...

Comment: @E.Shcherbo Nowadays some part of the code is just boilerplate and might looked mandatory to choose (even forced due to the fact is already the best choice) ... but still there are plenty of cases when a programmer can put own fingerprint.(even this case). Thanks for all comments.

Comment: I never wanted to say this, sorry that I made you think this way. Yeah, thanks for the discussion :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is how the operator "/" works.

```
int / int => int
int / float => float
float / int => float
```

Since you are doing an int division (int/int), the result will be an int, losing decimal information. If you want your division to be float or double, you have two options, either you declare the sum as double or you can just cast the division, so it becomes a double division instead of an int division.

```
averg = (double) sum / Scores.size();
```